# Windows batch command equivalent of "curl -s -L http://j.mp/script.sh | bash"

Tags: windows, scripting, batch

I would like to run a batch script that calls another batch script hosted on the internet. In bash, this can be done using something like this:

```
curl -s -L http://j.mp/script.sh | bash
```

How can I achieve this in windows batch. I have busybox and curl available but no powershell.

I looked around, but maybe I am using the wrong keywords as I cannot find what I am after.

Comment: Something like  `curl whatever > temp.bat && cmd /C temp.bat`

Comment: In the end I hacked it with curl -o something then call something then del something. But I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Well... there is a better way, but you said no PowerShell and didn't mention being on a company network, so you can't use group policies, PowerShell package managers, DSC, or even Invoke-Expression. You're stuck in the 1980s.